# How to do a jump based on cmpss output (floating-point compare)?

Tags: assembly, x86

According to this [reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_40.html), I can compare if xmm1 and xmm2 are equal by doing the following:

```
cmpss xmm2, xmm1, 0
```

However, it seems that the zero flag is not set. Instead, the result is stored in xmm2. How do I do a jump based on whether or not they're equal if instructions like `je` or `jz` rely on the zero flag?

Comment: Looks like intel forgot to add the `Flags affected` section to the SIMD instructions. This is normally mentioned for the integer instructions. *Hm, seems like they randomly added it whenever they felt like it ...

Comment: AMD seem to have done a better job, their manual does explicitly say `rFLAGS Affected None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cmpss` and its friends are more meant to give you masks that you can do branchless computation with, you could extract it to a GPR and then test that and so on but that's all a bit verbose and unnecessary.

If you want to branch, `ucomiss` (or `comiss`, depending on what you want to do with NaNs) is a better fit. Maybe like this:

```
ucomiss xmm2, xmm1
jp unordered
jz equal
```